# DropDownList.SelectedItem sometimes null, sometimes not after postback, EnableViewState=False

Tags: asp.net

I have two very similar .aspx pages. Both of them contain a DropDownList control. Both DropDownList controls' EnableViewState is set to False:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" />
```

There is a LinkButton on both pages. In the btn_Click handler, if I try to access ddl.SelectedItem property (which, as far as I know, should be null because of the EnableViewState=False, am I correct?), it is null on one page, but not null (it has a correct value) on the other page. Can you give me any pointers how can that be possible?

```
string txt = ddl.SelectedItem.Text; // SelectedItem sometimes null, other times not
```

The difference between those two pages's dropdowns is, that in one case, the dropdown is filled using AjaxToolkit's CascadingDropDown control (in that case, SelectedItem is not null, despite having EnableViewState property set to false), in the other case, dropdown's items are being filled in the Page_Load property, within and if-block, checking whether IsPostBack is false (items are only filled on the first request, I won't need them after the postback).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CascadingDropDown doesn't honor the enable viewstate setting. If you need it null, you should reset it to null on page load or a similar event.

Comment: That is the piece of information I did not have, thank you very much.

Actually, it was the other way around. I was converting CascadingDropDown in an "over-ajaxified" application into a regular DropDown and I was wondering, how could accessing the SelectedItem property ever work with the EnableViewState being false.

Thanks you, Stephen.

Comment: The control toolkit still has a lot of unexpected inconsistencies like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something populating the drop-down through JavaScript then ASP.NET will see that value, irrespective of how it got there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the selected index gets posted back to the server when you change the value; the selected index property gets applied once items are applied in the list, so if you have no items, I don't believe it gets applied until some items get added to the list.  So, if you bind the list again, and a value got selected from the list, and you rebind the drop down, it would apply the selected index.  That could be it possibly.

HTH